# R markdown define macros for formatting

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown

I've been wondering if there's a way to define a command in markdown (or R markdown, more specifically) in such a way that you don't have to insert the html formatting each time for frequent bits.

For example, I've been using the 'alert alert-info' class of css to insert 'Note' blocks throughout documents like so :

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Note :</strong><br/>
  stuff here
</div>
```

Since faster is better :) can I automate this? (I've tried using the `$\newcommand{}$` from latex to do this but the whole html code just gets printed in math mode on the page...)

**Edit :**

I sometimes add code chunks in the notes so it'd be nice if that worked as well.

Not having to escape '\' for LaTeX would be good (although it'd be a rather small price to pay if a new command is that much faster).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `htmltool` package we can build  a simple function to repeat the note, provided that you can script it:

```
library(htmltools)

alert_note <- function(text) {

  div(class="alert alert-info",
      strong('Note :'), br(),
      text)
}


alert_note('stuff here')
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Note :</strong>
  <br/>
  stuff here
</div>
```

To use it in a `.Rmd` document you define the function somewhere -probably in a setup chunk- and use it in a *not echoed* chunk

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "5/4/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}    
library(htmltools)

strong_alert <- function(text) { 
  div(class="alert alert-info",
      strong('Note :'), br(),
      text)
}
```
## R Markdown    
This is an R Markdown document.

```{r echo=FALSE}
strong_alert('stuff here')
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is pretty nice for text and all (although almost as long as including the html code for this particular case, I can see it useful for more elaborate formatting)  but I sometimes add a code chunk in these notes, which doesn't work through this method. There is also the problem that you need to escape every '\' for including LaTeX.