# How to do an r chunk within a block chunk in bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm in the midst of writing a textbook. I frequently use [custom code blocks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html) to explain technical concepts. These are quite nice, but sometimes I want to embed an r chunk within a custom code block. As an example, I would like to do the following:

````
```{block, type="rmdnote"}
This is a very tricky concept to master. Let's look at a plot and output generated from R:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
summary(1:10)
```
```
````

This will not work. Is there any way to embed an r chunk within a custom chunk?

Comment: Unfortunately, like in [this post from 2y ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52352747/6478701) there's a good chance it's impossible. I did a similar thing to what you want directly with div elements. [Here's an old post of mine with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50169490/6478701) (edit: there's no code chunk in the example, but I know it works). It's not a block, but likely the closest thing to what you want.